# Java: Difference between CaretListener and ChangeListener on a Caret

Tags: java, swing, caret

I was recently having an issue with a `CaretListener` attached to a `JTextArea` not getting fired, even when the caret moved (or seemed to move). What seemed to solve this was to instead attach a `ChangeListener` directly to the `JTextArea's` Caret, with:

```
textArea.getCaret().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
//Implemented method here
});
```

So now my question is, what's the *difference* technically between these approaches? How could this get fired when the `CaretListener` attached to the text area doesn't? (If it helps, there is a scenario and a code example of the `CaretListener` not being fired on my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40339741/java-swing-caret-listener-stops-firing-after-jpopupmenu-is-shown/).)

Comment: Looked at your last question earlier and couldn't figure out why the CaretListener didn't fire. Seems like a bug to me. Something in the state of the textarea/caret was not being reset after the popup was displayed (until you actually clicked on the text area with the mouse again). So I would say there is no real difference. They should both generate events. If you really want to know the difference then you need to debug the code and step through it statement by statement to see why the CaretEvent is not generated and the ChangeEvent is.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying that for me @camickr. I appreciate it. :)